# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';' (Magic numbers in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have an issue that a previously fully working piece of HTML / Javascript was throwing errors in very specific instances.

The error thrown was:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'

Recorded in the browser console. This error was **only thrown on the first load of the page**, ie when a form was submitted. Refreshing the page ***always*** caused a flawless load with no console errors in any form.

The javascript was inline script setting map icons for Leaflet map and some variables for leaflet map and a flag for if to use Javascript Local Storage:

```
<script>
/* Leaflet flags.... there are about 20 of these loaded */
    var auxIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/images/map_icons/auxIcon.png',
    iconSize:     [18, 24],
    iconAnchor:   [0, 24],
    popupAnchor:  [10, -20]
}); /*@*/
var vgsIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/images/map_icons/VGS_30.png',
    iconSize:     [25, 30],
    iconAnchor:   [0, 30],
    popupAnchor:  [10, -15]
}); /*@*/
var zoomValueLevel = 5; /*@*//* Map zoom level */
var useLS = 1; /*@*//* Use local storage for Leaflet map position? */

if(useLS === true && localStorage.getItem('zoomLevel')) {
    zoomValueLevel = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('zoomLevel'));
}
...
...
</script>
```

The error always indicates `;` was at fault, and an expression was expected. However the error appeared in various different places, apparently arbitarily.

The error occurred at every location marked as a `/*@*/` above,

I have no idea why this was occuring but had not been occuring before. Various other questions on Stack Overflow relating to very similar error feedbacks have highlighted syntax faults or issues but I can't see what is wrong here, yet was always correct on reload, when nothing had actually changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what it was;

I looked closely at the variable setting; and found that the `zoomValueLevel` and `useLS` vars both using something that JSHint (on PhpStorm) was complaining about "magic numbers"; these values were somehow special whereby a variable was given a numeric value without quote marks.

So; I did two things: I updated the flag value to a true boolean rather than a 0/1 pseudo-boolean value so its output was actually `true` or `false` and I set the Zoom level to the same numeric value as before but within single quotes.

I don't know why this error occurred only on first load of the page and was error free at other times, I also don't know why this error hasn't shown itself before, but the solution seems to be to remove what JSHint calls "magic numbers" and always wrap numbers in quote marks and use full textual representations for boolean flag variables.

```
var zoomValueLevel = '5';
var useLS = true;
```

This instantly removed the issue and the page now never feedsback any console errors when loading. I hope this is useful to someone.